# Undefined reference to _EEPROM_start when using Mixiaoxiao's HomeKit framework on esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, nodemcu, homekit

I'm using a homekit framework by Mixiaoxiao for the esp8266 to create a diy homekit controllable smart blind. I'm pretty sure I've solved all of the issues I was having with my own code (hopeful thinking lol), but now I'm getting the following errors. I'm pretty sure the issue lies within the library I used, but unsure on a fix.

```
/home/builder/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: /tmp/arduino-build-3009112EB8599B216613EB82652E81F5/libraries/HomeKit-ESP8266/storage.c.o:(.text.find_empty_block+0x0): undefined reference to `_EEPROM_start'

/home/builder/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: /tmp/arduino-build-3009112EB8599B216613EB82652E81F5/libraries/HomeKit-ESP8266/storage.c.o: in function `homekit_storage_reset':

/mnt/create-efs/webide/29/f3/29f32a690ec98f2e231ae59981834f97:paul2357/libraries_v2/HomeKit-ESP8266/src/storage.c:137: undefined reference to `_EEPROM_start'

/home/builder/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: /mnt/create-efs/webide/29/f3/29f32a690ec98f2e231ae59981834f97:paul2357/libraries_v2/HomeKit-ESP8266/src/storage.c:140: undefined reference to `_EEPROM_start'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error during build: exit status 1
```

**What I tried:**

Tried posting to git, but scrolling through issues shows that nothing has been addressed by the dev since about 2021

Tried searching for how to solve this issue and tried adding #include <EEPROM.h> based on something I saw online

Any tips on how I can solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

updating the esp8266 core fixed this for me ;)